# Cyclic dependency in two Mongoose models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a cyclic dependency problem with two mongoose schemas which depend on each other. Code is as follows:

```
// user.model.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var transactionSchema = mongoose.model('Transaction').schema;

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema ({
  name : String,
  wallet: Number,
  transactions: [ {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Transaction'} ]
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

// transaction.model.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var userSchema = mongoose.model('User').schema;

var transactionSchema = mongoose.Schema ({
  sourceUser: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  targetUser: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  amount: Number,
  status: String
});

var Transaction = mongoose.model('Transaction', transactionSchema);
```

Loaded as such:

```
// app.js
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('./models/user.model');
require('./models/transaction.model');
```

Issue is obvious but unclear how to solve.

Comment: why do you need to import `userSchema` in transaction file? It's not used. same thing goes for `transactionSchema`.

Comment: its used as sourceUser and target user referencers

Comment: no it's not. you don't need to require it. `ref: 'User'` doesn't mean that you should define the `User` collection earlier. it will work just fine.

Comment: i see, problem solved. I thought the schemas were necessary for refererence, but I was mistaken. thank you

Answer (score -3):

### user.model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema ({
  name : String,
  wallet: Number,
  transactions: [ {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Transaction'} ]
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

### transaction.model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var transactionSchema = mongoose.Schema ({
  sourceUser: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  targetUser: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  amount: Number,
  status: String
});

var Transaction = mongoose.model('Transaction', transactionSchema);
```